# Accessing class variables of subclass from superclass constructor in python (with details)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I know if I have to check some regex pattern in constructor, the code should be something like this:

```py
import re


class Alphabet:
    pattern = re.compile("^[A-Z]*$")

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.string = "".join(args)
        self.check()

    def check(self):
        if not Alphabet.pattern.match(self.string):
            raise ValueError

    def some_methods(self):
        ...


class A(Alphabet):
    pattern = re.compile("^A*$")

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args)

    def check(self):
        if not A.pattern.match(self.string):
            raise ValueError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Alphabet("AB", "C", "DE") #Nothing happens
    A("AA", "B", "AAAA") #ValueError
```

But how about this? If I replace the `check` method in class `Alphabet` with the below code and remove the `check` method in class `A`, then I don't have to re-write the `check` method twice (which serves almost the same role in the two classes).

```py
def check(self):
    if not self.pattern.match(self.string):
        raise ValueError
```

Is this not preferable? I've checked the two scripts produce equivalent results.

Comment: yes, using `self` to access a class variable (not an instance variable) is completely normal. It could also be a `@classmethod` too

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I'm confused because I also study Java language. The Java linter warns me every time I try to use expressions like ```this.static_something``` , with message "accessing static variable in a non-static context".

Comment: Well rest assured, Python isn't Java :)